# Windows 10: Thumbnails not loading during FILE OPEN dialogue

Tags: windows, windows-10, dialog

I've a windows 10 x 64 computer with highend specifications. 
OS is also installed on a performance SSD. Etc.

My problem is during file-open and other similar dialogues, the thumbnails takes an extremely long time to load/show up. I get this:

[image]

Sometimes it doesn't even load at all.

But when i visit that same folder DIRECTLY from Explorer, the thumbnails load really fast.

[image]

So I'm sure this is some sort of a problem with explorer yes? If so how does one fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

We can try the following two ways to accelerate speed of loading or showing the thumbnails:

**Way 1**:modify local group policy

1.Open "Run" with "Win+R".

2.Type "gpedit.msc", click "OK", open "Local Group Policy Editor".

3.Locate to "User configuration->Administrative Templates->Windows Components->File Explorer->Turn off caching of thumbnail pictures".

4.Enable "Turn off caching of thumbnail pictures", click "Apply" and "OK".

5.Logoff the user account and logon the user account again, we can view if the speed of loading or showing the thumbnails is faster.

[image]

**Way 2**:modify the registry

1.Open "Run" with "Win+R".

2.Type "regedit.exe", click "OK".

3.Locate to "Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Mouse\MouseHoverTime".

4.Modify the "Value date" to a value smaller than 400, click "OK" (the default "Value data" is 400).

5.Restart the computer to view if the speed of loading or showing the thumbnails is faster.

[image]